# How to force vbscript to display a string in left to right direction

Tags: vbscript

How to make the String go from left to right.

```vbs
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
objSelection.Style = "No Spacing"
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're looking for: left-to-right justification, or for the String to appear as `gnicapS oN`.  [This page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176990.aspx) may contain an answer.

Comment: sorry i was not clear. my script make a outlook signature. i want her to go LTR and bot RTL

Comment: I'm still not understanding exactly @user3061949 -- please show an example of what you want the output to be.

Comment: i am trying to make table that contain picture and string. and make it at outlook signature. my problem is that the table align\direction to right. i want it to start from left